# Schema.org WebPage - isPartOf?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I'm trying to figure out how to use the `isPartOf` attribute in the [Schema.org `WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage) object.

From what I understand, this should be used to specify that your page is part of a collection. So so I have a list of hockey teams and then a list of players. My understanding is that an individual player would be a part of the team, so presumably on the players HTML page, I would add the `isPartOf` element.

But I'm not sure how I would add this. Should I add it as a URL to the pages collection? Or should I just add a `meta` tag with the collections name? I can't seem to find much about this element anywhere. Does anyone know how to properly use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're right: use `isPartOf` to indicate the parent collection (team, in this case) to which a page or file (player) belongs.

So on the player's page:

`<a href="/toronto-maple-leafs/" itemprop="isPartOf">Member of the Toronto Maple Leafs</a>`

And on the team page, ensure that it's marked with CollectionPage, for example:

`<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CollectionPage">`

Answer (score 2):

The [`isPartOf`](http://schema.org/isPartOf) property (and [its inverse property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41497624/1591669): [`hasPart`](http://schema.org/hasPart)) can be used to convey that a `CreativeWork` is part of another `CreativeWork`. One use case is a category page ([example](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/98556/17633)).

While a URL value could be used, the expected way is to provide `CreativeWork` values (`WebPage` is a more specific `CreativeWork`):

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Child page</h1>
  <p itemprop="isPartOf" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
    <span itemprop="name">Parent page</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Parent page</h1>
  <p itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
    <span itemprop="name">Child page</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

#### For a sports team

However, if you want to convey that a player is part of a team, you can’t use `isPartOf`/`hasPart`, as players and teams aren’t creative works. You would need a suitable property that can connect `Person` and `Organization` items.

Schema.org has suitable types and properties for this case now:

- [`SportsTeam`](http://schema.org/SportsTeam)

  > Organization: Sports team.
- [`athlete`](http://schema.org/athlete)

  > A person that acts as performing member of a sports team; a player as opposed to a coach.

Example:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SportsTeam">
  <ul>
    <li itemprop="athlete" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"></li>
    <li itemprop="athlete" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"></li>
    <li itemprop="athlete" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The `athlete` property has no inverse property defined. If you want to specify this relation within a `Person` item, you could either use the non-standard `itemprop-reverse` attribute ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38663388/1591669)), or switch from using Microdata to RDFa ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46018087/1591669)) or JSON-LD ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39331042/1591669)).