# Linking independent elements in Microdata

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I'm creating a site about an author. He is the main-topic. On this site his written books are shown, too.

Unfortunately, I can't find a solution to link these books to the main person-element. I tried `itemref`, but it doesn't work when linking to such 'independent' element, which has no `itemprop` value (says the Google testing tool). Both following "book"-cases don't work.

```html
<div id="author" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <span itemprop="name">Marvin</span>
</div>

<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
  <span itemprop="name">Nice Book</span>
  <meta itemprop="author" itemref="author" />
</div>

<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
  <span itemprop="name">Best Book</span>
  <meta itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemref="author" />
</div>
```

Has anybody another idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three options.

#### `itemid`

As [described by @Dharmang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38662358/1591669). You give the `Person` a URI (with the `itemid` attribute) and reference this URI in each `Book` with the `author` property.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemid="#person-1">
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
  <link itemprop="author" href="#person-1" />
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
  <link itemprop="author" href="#person-1" />
</div>
```

(This URI can then used by others that also want to say something about this person, or that want to identify that person. So `[your-domain]/[your-path]#person-1` is then a URI that represents the actual person, not just a page about that person. If there is already such a URI for that person, you might want to reuse it instead of creating your own.)

**Problem:** Consumer support might not be the best (but Google’s testing tool seems to recognize it).

#### `itemref`

You have to add `itemprop="author"` to the `Person` item, and reference its `id` from each `Book` with the `itemref` attribute. You don’t have to add a `meta` element for this, you simply do it on the element with the `itemscope`.

```html
<div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" id="author">
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book" itemref="author">
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book" itemref="author">
</div>
```

**Problem:** The `Person` item can’t have a parent with `itemscope` (because its `author` property would be added to it). So this means, for example, that you can’t use the `mainEntity` property to denote that the `Person` is the primary topic of the `WebPage`.

#### `itemprop-reverse`

If you can nest the `Book` items in the `Person` item, you could use the `itemprop-reverse` attribute, which allows you to use properties in the other direction:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">

  <div itemprop-reverse="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
  </div>

  <div itemprop-reverse="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
  </div>

</div>
```

(If you can’t nest, you could still use it with a URI value, but using `itemid` in that case is probably the better choice.)

**Problem:** This attribute is not part of the Microdata specification. It’s [defined in W3C’s *Microdata to RDF* Note](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-microdata-rdf-20141216/#dfn-itemprop-reverse). So consumer support might be not so good. Google’s testing tool doesn’t seem to recognize it.

Comment: Thank you, but as you mentioned the first two solutions will 'cut out' the person-element. When the third solution can't be read by googles testing tool, its crawler will probably do the same. It's tricky.

Comment: @Less: With "cut out", do you mean that Google’s testing tool does not display `Person` in an own section? If yes, that should be no problem: it only lists top-level items that way; all the other items are nested inside such a section (e.g., inside `Book` in your case). It’s just the way Google decided to display the output.

Comment: Yes, that are my thoughts. I don't think it's just a display issue of the testing tool. In my opinion Google will not see the `Person` as the main-entity of the document.

Comment: @Less: I think you have to *tell* consumers what the main entity should be. Having top-level items doesn’t convey that they are more important than nested items. To denote which item is the main entity, you can use the [`mainEntity` property](http://schema.org/mainEntity) (`WebPage` → `mainEntity` → `Person`) (or the inverse [`mainEntityOfPage`](http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage) if you don’t want a `WebPage` item).

Comment: Ok, I found your other help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466028/how-to-implement-mainentityofpage-to-this-specific-site
The testing tool still shows the book-elements as the top-level items, but with `mainEntityOfPage` it should be clear, that `Person` is the main topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `link` tag to achieve this, check below snippet:

```
<div itemid="#author-marvin" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <span itemprop="name">Marvin</span>
</div>
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
  <span itemprop="name">Nice Book</span>
  <link itemprop="author" href="#author-marvin">
</div>
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Book">
  <span itemprop="name">Best Book</span>
  <link itemprop="author" href="#author-marvin">
</div>
```

`itemid` of author snippet should match the `href` of `link` in book snippet throughout the page markup.

More examples [here](http://schema.org/Book)

Comment: Thank you, but in this solution only the book-schemas will be left over, and no instance of the person.