# Schema for an actor/actress Person

Tags: schema.org

How could I represent the [`Movie`](https://schema.org/Movie), [`TVSeries`](https://schema.org/TVSeries) or any other [`CreativeWork`](https://schema.org/CreativeWork) items a [`Person`](https://schema.org/Person) acted or participated in?

I mean, something like:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "http://schema.org/Person",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "performerIn" : [
    {
      "@type": "http://schema.org/Movie",
      "name": "A Movie"
    },
    {
      "@type": "http://schema.org/Movie",
      "name": "Another Movie"
    }
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately, [`performerIn`](https://schema.org/performerIn) works only for [`Event`](https://schema.org/Event) items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an actor in a `Movie`/`TVSeries`/etc., you can use the [`actor` property](http://schema.org/actor).

As Schema.org defines no inverse property for `actor`, you can use JSON-LD’s [`@reverse`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#reverse-properties):

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "@reverse": {"actor": [
    {
      "@type": "Movie",
      "name": "A Movie"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Movie",
      "name": "Another Movie"
    }
  ]}
}
```

For "participated in", it depends on what this means exactly. There are properties like [`contributor`](http://schema.org/contributor), [`editor`](http://schema.org/editor), etc. (Schema.org doesn’t offer properties for all roles a person could have in a creative work, but if it’s a common/important role, it might get added if you request it.)

Comment: [Google's testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) maps that to a collection of `Movie` entities, not exactly what I was looking for... but I think it will do the trick. Thanks!