# Schema.org telephone recommended

Tags: wordpress, schema.org, json-ld

I've been working on getting my local business in Google and want to implement JSON-LD, I'm not really familar with coding (wordpress user) so I used a generator to create the code, however when testing in Google's structured data test I get the warning/error that the field: Phone is recommended. Can someone check/see if there's something wrong in the way the code is build up? I've already tried myself in changing order etc. but that didn't give the result I was hoping for.

```
<script type='application/ld+json'> 
{
  "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
  "@type": "ProfessionalService",
  "name": "Met Lidy kinder- en jeugdcoaching",
  "url": "https://website.nl/",
  "logo": "https://website.nl",
  "image": "https://website.nl",
  "description": "Description",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "Adress",
    "addressLocality": "City",
    "addressRegion": "Noord-Brabant",
    "postalCode": "5000AA",
    "addressCountry": "Netherlands"
  },
  "geo": {
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude": "51.000000",
    "longitude": "4.000000"
  },
  "openingHours": "Mo 13:30-18:00 Tu, We 09:00-18:00",
  "contactPoint": {
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "telephone": "+123456789",
    "contactType": "reservations"
  }
}
 </script>
```

**Edit** Changed back details to 'general' text

Comment: It probably doesn’t matter practically, but it might be preferable to use the canonical `@context`: `http://schema.org` (instead of `http://www.schema.org`)

Answer (score 0):

From Schema.org’s perspective, your data is perfectly fine. Schema.org never requires a property.

Google’s SDTT would like to see the `telephone` property for the `ProfessionalService` entity. You are providing the `telephone` property for the `ContactPoint` entity.

Unless you try to get a Google rich result which makes use of `ProfessionalService`-`telephone`, you can keep your data like it is. If there is such a rich result, if you don’t want warnings in the SDTT, simply add the `telephone` property (you can keep your `ContactPoint`, if you prefer):

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "ProfessionalService",

  "telephone": "+31628488435"

}
```

---

In case you don’t know, the `ProfessionalService` type [is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40286486/1591669).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I wasn't aware that the ProfessionalService type was deprecated but selected it because the other types didn't fit with the business. Might be best to change it from ProfessionalService to LocalBusiness in that case?

Comment: @Joeri: It might not be necessary for your case, but I would always try to avoid deprecated types. `LocalBusiness` could represent your business, and `Service`/`Offer`/etc. can represent what the business does.