# Representing repeating attributes in JSON-LD

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I would like to know how to represent repeating attributes using JSON-LD ([recommended](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data) by Google) and Schema.org specifications. For example, how should we represent an [`Article`](https://schema.org/Article) with *N* [`Comment`](https://schema.org/Comment)s (N > 1)?

It is allowed to have an array as `comment` value like my example below. Seems yes as [Google testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/) likes it.

But it is allowed to use a *flat* `@graph` representation instead? How? I have to evolve a site and this representation could be easier to implement.

I imagine that both are allowed? Then how to choose?

My example:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context" : "http:\/\/schema.org",
  "@type" : "Article",
  "url" : "https:\/\/exemple.com/article?id=1234",
  "author" :{"@type" : "Person","name" : "Didier"},
  "image" : "https:\/\/exemple.com/article.jpg",
  "mainEntityOfPage" : "https:\/\/exemple.com",
  "dateModified" : "2018-06-14T19:50:02+02:00",
  "datePublished" : "2018-06-14T19:50:02+02:00",
  "publisher" : {"@type" : "Organization","name" : "exemple.com", "logo" : {"@type" : "ImageObject", "url" : "https:\/\/exemple.com\/logo.png"}},
  "headline" : "my article",
  "text" : "blah blah",
  "commentCount" : 2,
  "comment" : [{
      "author" : {"@type" : "Person", "name" : "Didier"},
      "text" : "comment first!!",
      "dateCreated" : "2018-06-14T21:40:00+02:00"
},{
      "author" : {"@type" : "Person", "name" : "Robert"},
      "text" : "second comment",
      "dateCreated" : "2018-06-14T23:23:00+02:00"
}]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most simple (and most supported) way is to provide an array as value, like in your snippet:

```json
"comment": [
  {"@type": "Comment"},
  {"@type": "Comment"}
]
```

If you want to use multiple top-level items ([with `@graph` or other options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48295719/1591669)), you need a way to convey that these top-level `Comment` items are comments for an `Article`.

[With `@id`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34776122/1591669), you can give each item a URI and reference this URI as property value instead of nesting the item:

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@type": "Article",
      "@id": "/articles/foobar",
      "comment": [
        {"@id": "/articles/foobar#comment-1"},
        {"@id": "/articles/foobar#comment-2"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "@type": "Comment",
      "@id": "/articles/foobar#comment-1"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Comment",
      "@id": "/articles/foobar#comment-2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Instead of listing the comment URIs under `Article`, you could also refer to the `Article` within each `Comment`, [with `@reverse`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39331042/1591669):

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@type": "Article",
      "@id": "/articles/foobar"
    },
    {
      "@type": "Comment",
      "@id": "/articles/foobar#comment-1",
      "@reverse": {"comment": {"@id": "/articles/foobar"}}
    },
    {
      "@type": "Comment",
      "@id": "/articles/foobar#comment-2",
      "@reverse": {"comment": {"@id": "/articles/foobar"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: (excellent, thanks unor!)
To be 100% complete, I update your code snapshot to get a (Google tool) valid sample equivalent of myExample. cf. Gist https://gist.github.com/boly38/0935d8b0a83b7a2fe4254fa2a6b92113

Comment: Thanks @unor for sharing this. I was playing for hours getting a connection between an array of Reviews into a Product. It seems that (at least Googles Structured Data Test Tool) cannot understand [named graphs](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#named-graphs) yet.