# The difference between isPartOf and hasPart in Schema.org?

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

What is the difference between the Schema.org properties `isPartOf` and `hasPart` and when to use the one instead of the other?

Comment: If you had a cheese sandwich then cheese is a part of the cheese sandwich, and a cheese sandwich has a part which is cheese.

Answer (score 4):

As noted on their pages, they are *inverse properties*.

As an example, let’s take a webpage that is part of a website. You could then state one of these:

- `WebSite` `hasPart` `WebPage`
- `WebPage` `isPartOf` `WebSite`

It doesn’t matter which one you choose. (But there might of course be consumers that only recognize one of these properties.)

Note: Most of the time, Schema.org doesn’t define an inverse equivalent for a property. For example, there is [`author`](http://schema.org/author), but no <s>`authorOf`</s>. This is because you can use every property for both directions, with the help of the syntax:

- RDFa:
  [**`rev`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-rdfa-core-20150317/#A-rev)
  ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46018087/1591669))
- Microdata:
  [**`itemprop-reverse`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-microdata-rdf-20141216/#dfn-itemprop-reverse) (non-standard, which is one of the reasons to [prefer RDFa over Microdata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669))
  ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38663388/1591669))
- JSON-LD:
  [**`@reverse`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#reverse-properties)
  ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39331042/1591669))