# "mainEntityOfPage" and "CreativeWork" usage on a web page of type "Organization"

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I have a question regarding the correct use of the `mainEntityOfPage`, in this scenario:

1. The homepage of the site is of `Organization` type with name, description of the company, phone, address etc.
2. At the bottom of this page I have 3 snippets to 3 different articles published by this company.
3. So, I am trying to declare the homepage of `Organization` type, being the main topic of the web page. Also, I would like to declare using Schema.org that this company has written 3 different articles which are located on their own web pages. These snippets consists of headline of article, an introducing paragraph, a picture and a "read more" button.

I use the following code:

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" >
<a href="https://testsite.com/index.html" itemprop="url">
<img src="https://testsite.com/img/logo.jpg" itemprop="logo" alt="Company logo" />
</a>
<p itemprop="name">Company name</p>
<p itemprop="description">Company description</p>

<div itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/CreativeWork">
<meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="https://testsite.com/img/article-1-picture.jpg" />
<p itemprop="headline">Article 1 headline</p>
<p itemprop="description">Article 1 first paragraph.</p>
<a itemprop="url" href="https://testsite.com/url-article-1.html">Read more</a>
</div>

<div itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/CreativeWork">
<meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="https://testsite.com/img/article-2-picture.jpg" />
<p itemprop="headline">Article 2 headline</p>
<p itemprop="description">Article 2 first paragraph.</p>
<a itemprop="url" href="https://testsite.com/url-article-2.html">Read more</a>
</div>

<div itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/CreativeWork">
<meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" content="https://testsite.com/img/article-3-picture.jpg" />
<p itemprop="headline">Article 3 headline</p>
<p itemprop="description">Article 3 first paragraph.</p>
<a itemprop="url" href="https://testsite.com/url-article-3.html">Read more</a>
</div>
</body>
```

The code above generates the following schema:

[image: Result of the code validation on Structured Data Testing Tool]

The code is valid with Structured Data Testing Tool.

I am afraid that using `mainEntityOfPage` here, 3 times, to introduce the article snippets would result into the situation that the search engine would wrongly consider my page of type `CreativeWork` rather than `Organization` type, which is the real main topic on this web page.

So, this code says to the search engine that the page is of `Organization` with 3 articles on separate pages, or only `CreativeWork` type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structured data is not conveying what you intend to convey. It’s saying that the `Organization` is the primary entity on the three `CreativeWork`s.

> So, I am trying to declare the homepage of `Organization` type, being the main topic of the web page.

For this, you need a `WebPage` item that represents the homepage.

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">

  <div itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
    <link itemprop="url" href="https://example.com/" /> <!-- the canonical URL of your homepage -->
  </div>

</body>
```

> I would like to declare using Schema.org that this company has written 3 different articles which are located on their own web pages.

For this, you need properties that say how the company and the articles¹ are related, like:

- [`publisher`](https://schema.org/publisher)
- [`author`](https://schema.org/author)
- etc.

Note that, for example, `publisher` is only defined for one direction (an article has a publisher), not for the other one (an organization has published an article).² So you have to provide this property in the `Article`, not in the `Organization`.

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">

  <div itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemPage">
    <link itemprop="url" href="https://example.com/url-article-1.html" /> <!-- the canonical URL of the article page -->
  </div>

  <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <link itemprop="url" href="https://example.com/" /> <!-- the canonical URL of the organization’s homepage -->
  </div>

</article>
```

---

¹ if they actually are *articles*, you should use the [`Article`](https://schema.org/Article) type instead of the parent type `CreativeWork`

² Microdata (in contrast to RDFa and JSON-LD) offers only a non-standardized way to use these properties in the other direction: [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41497624/1591669)